# How to print the sentence based on assigned number

Tags: vb.net

I currently have a program in which when you type the sentence it sorts it like so:

```
1, 2, 3, 1, 
test:1 testing:2 example:3
```

So the sentence would be 'test testing test hi example test'

This is stored in a text file so what would be the best way to retrieve the sentence by the numbers set to each word and how to retrieve them from the file.

Comment: What is stored in the text file? Is it the numbers only? The numbers and words? or the full sentence?

Comment: Everything that I had included on 2 seperate lines